# How do I prevent XSL unescaping characters?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using an XSLT to convert XML in one format to XML in another format (differently-named elements, attributes) but preserving the data. The data contains a lot of escaped non-ASCII characters, such as &eacute; or &copy; and I want to preserve that in the output. (It's being fed into another system, which will only accept escaped characters.)

Here's a representative sample:

`<para>avant de cro&icirc;tre en <i>automne</i>, et de former un dip&ocirc;le de type ONA en hiver. Les d&eacute;placements dans l&apos;espace et le temps des r&eacute;gions</para>`

My problem is that when I run the XSL (in Altova XMLSpy, if it makes a difference) the output becomes

`<p>avant de croître en <italic>automne</italic>, et de former un dipôle de type ONA en hiver. Les déplacements dans l'espace et le temps des régions</p>`

(The tag conversions are correct.)

My XSL is

```
<xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:element name="p" xmlns="http://jats.nlm.nih.gov">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:element name="italic" xmlns="http://jats.nlm.nih.gov">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

(Apologies if this is bad. I'm new to this.)

How do I get the XSL to copy *exactly* the text presented, without unescaping the characters, but also looking 'inside' the node to transform any sub-elements like `<i>`?

Comment: There is no pure XSLT way to preserve character references, if you want the output to use character references for certain characters then with XSLT 2, which Altova supports, you can set up a character map that maps each character to its reference. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps.

Comment: With XML output, the intent of XSL is to preserve the meaning, not the format.